# Is there any way to access the same minio UI which gets deployed by kubeflow from cloud shell?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, minio, kubeflow

In short, we have deployed kubeflow on GKE & as we know that minio comes pre-installed with kubeflow. On kubeflow UI, one can see that several pipeline artifacts are referencing minio for storage.In order to access that minio UI, I went on to expose the minio service on the specified port using port forwarding in the cloud shell. I accessed that minio UI using web preview option in cloud shell but could not find any buckets on Minio UI which are present on Kubeflow UI & not able to create buckets on minio UI too.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for your requirement. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use minio for any kubeflow service (pipeline runs storage, kserve model location, etc).

Expose minio:

```
theofpa@luna:~$ kubectl port-forward -n kubeflow svc/minio-service 9000:9000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 9000
Forwarding from [::1]:9000 -> 9000
```

Now that you have it forwarded, you can access it using the [minio cli](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide.html), by default it comes with the `local` alias configured already:

```
theofpa@luna:~$ mc alias ls local
local
  URL       : http://localhost:9000
  AccessKey : 
  SecretKey : 
  API       : 
  Path      : auto
```

Just add the authentication details (I've got them from the secret `mlpipeline-minio-artifact`):

```
theofpa@luna:~$ mc alias set local http://localhost:9000 minio minio123
Added `local` successfully.
```

And you're ready to use it:

```
theofpa@luna:~$ mc ls local
[2021-10-12 11:25:43 CEST]     0B mlpipeline/
theofpa@luna:~$ mc mb local/models
Bucket created successfully `local/models`.
theofpa@luna:~$ mc ls local
[2021-10-12 11:25:43 CEST]     0B mlpipeline/
[2021-10-12 14:37:14 CEST]     0B models/
```

These buckets should be accessible by the UI as well. If you still have problems, perform some basic k8s checks. There should be a `pvc` called `minio-pvc` bounded and the deployment/pod called `minio` should be in ready state.